# Need help for Regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex expression which will allow following types of input in javascript :-

1,-,2

1,2,-

-,1,2

-

1,2

1

I need it for validation in my website which will allow only above set of values, Please not there could be only one hypen(-) in any case.
1 or 2 in above case can be any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is what you need:

```
^([\d-]+(,[\d-]+)*)?$
```

Tested via https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks, but it's accepting multiple "-". As per my requirement I should have maximum one "-" in whole input string.

Comment: for e.g    1,2,-,-    is not allowed.

Comment: GOT IT           "^-(,[0-9]+)*$|^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*(,-)?(,[0-9]+)*$|^[0-9]+(,-)?(,[0-9]+)*$"

Comment: Just a word of advice.
Don't make things, especially when it comes to regex, too complicated.

You could have easily combined 2 regex's or use str.match combined with my original to achieve this.

But glad you have what you need.